# RemoveScheduledTask has some problem in Mathematica 11

Tags: scheduling

I am using Mathematica 11

below is an simple example of `RunScheduledTask` copied [from documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RunScheduledTask.html#437145416).

```
n = 0; Dynamic[n]
RunScheduledTask[n++, {1, 3}];
```

After running it, it will count 3 seconds

Now run

```
RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]];
```

you will find the kernel quited!! This can be seen from the fact the variable `n` becomes blue again. Is this normal?

Comment: It doesn't crash for me but takes to much time to evaluate. Moreover, from time to time `ScheduledTasks[]` contains 1-9 internal tasks related to paclet manager...

Comment: @Kuba have you notice `n` becomes blue?

Comment: No because it does not quit the kernel for my case.

Comment: @Kuba This is quite odd ! Look at what I ran http://pasteboard.co/e4LWxeBwY.png  kernel really quit. Wait for other people to confirm this.

Comment: Works fine for me using Mathematica 11.0 under Windows 10.

Comment: Also works fine for me, v11 under Windows 10.

Comment: @Karsten7. Ok, this is odd. Though I am using win8, but it is not likely due to windows system. I don't know what is wrong with my M11

Comment: Works also fine for me, v11 installed today under Windows 10.

Comment: Does `ScheduledTasks[]` return something else as `{ }` before and after running your code?

Comment: @Karsten7. it returns nothing

Comment: Works fine for me (V11.0.0, Linux Mint 17.3)